# Differentiating an integral correctness and conditions

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The goal is to turn the integral below in a differential form

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k(x)p(x,t)dx = H(t) 
$$

Where $p(x,t)$ is a probability density function whether it matters or not I don't know. Anyways, I procced as follows:

$$
\frac{\partial H(t)}{\color{red}\partial \color{red}x} = k(x)p(x,t) \\ 
$$

$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{\partial H(t)}{\cancel{\color{red}\partial \color{red}t}}\frac{\cancel{\color{red}\partial \color{red}t}}{\color{red}\partial \color{red}x} = k(x)p(x,t) \\
$$

$$
{\partial H(t)} = k(x)p(x,t)\color{red}{\partial x}
$$

Is there anything I have to watch out for, is this allowed, or is this even close to being correct at all?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What you're trying to do makes no sense. However you manipulate it, you'll always have a definite integral. In terms of an inner product on functions, it's like trying to dismantle $k\cdot p(t)=H(t)$.

Comment: @J.G.Are you saying that is impossible to write the first equation in differential form, or that equation 1 is wrong in itself?

Comment: I'm saying the former.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot differentiate with respect to $x$ like this, notice how the right is not a function of $x$ so its differential would be $0$, if you were to it would tell you:
$$k(\infty)p(\infty,t)-k(\infty)p(\infty,t)=0$$
however you can differentiate with respect to $t$ if that helps in this situation. Also notice above that $t$ is not defined as a function of $x$ and so: $\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}=0$